# Include JS files only on iPad (Ionic)

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, ionic-framework

I'm doing one Ionic App and I'm trying to load some JS/CSS files but only if is iPad. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Meeting App</title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

    // if ( is_ipad() ) : 
         <script src="css/just-ipad.css"></script>
         <script src="js/just-ipad.js"></script>
    // endif;
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" align-title="center">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this could be do it in the **index.html**. There will be files used in all the iPad views but not in the mobile views.

I know that I can use the [Platform Classes](http://ionicframework.com/docs/platform-customization/platform-classes.html) but this doesn't cover my needs. I'm very new in Ionic and I don't know if this is possible.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add OR load file dynamically

1. Check for device if it is ipad ?
2. If its true then add your desired files this way (Script OR style).

   ```
   If(ionic.Platform.isIPad()){
       var script = document.createElement("script");
       script.src = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&callback=loadGoogleMapsApiReady";
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
   }
   ```

Regards.

Comment: This looks nice, I will try it and will tell you if works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you are looking for [`ionic.Platform.isIPad();`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/) method as can be seen in the link provided.

**Documentation**

```
isIPad()

Returns: boolean Whether we are running on iPad.
```

**Usage**

It seems that they have some other helper functions as can be seen from the code snippet from their site below.

```
angular.module('PlatformApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PlatformCtrl', function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
  });

  var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();

  var isWebView = ionic.Platform.isWebView();
  var isIPad = ionic.Platform.isIPad();
  var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
  var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
  var isWindowsPhone = ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone();

  var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
  var currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();

  ionic.Platform.exitApp(); // stops the app
});
```

**ProTip**

I simply Googled the following:

*ionic check platform*

and clicked the first link. In the future, consider using Google first.

**Reading Material**

[`ionic.Platform`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

Comment: I know that function, thanks. But can I use it inside the index.html? To load or not the files in the html? Or there is another way to load the files?